FE Practice Question: How to use the given formula?
For this problem, the answer states to use the given formula. However, I'm not sure how to use it as it involves solving the square root of a complex number. Additionally, I'm not quite sure how the solution got 1/(2.998*10^8) when solving sqrt(uo x epsilono) from the given propagation constant equation.



The algebra needed to find the square root of a complex number is easy to imagine:$$\begin{align*}y&=\sqrt{x}\\\left(y_r+j,y_i\right)^2&=x_r+j,x_i\\\left(y_r^2-y_i^2\right)+j,2,y_r,y_i&=x_r+j,x_i\\\text{so it's just two equations and two unknowns:}\\y_r^2-y_i^2&=x_r\\2,y_r,y_i&=x_i\end{align*}$$ A solution will likely yield two possible answers that make sense. Each the negation of the other.


I'm not sure how to use it as it involves solving the square root of a
complex number.

Convert the complex number to a magnitude and phase. Then take the square root of the magnitude and halve the phase angle. Then convert back to a complex number and that's the square root solved.

Additionally, I'm not quite sure how the solution got 1/(2.99810^8)
when solving sqrt(uo x epsilono)*

The speed of light in free space is \$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\mu_0\epsilon_0}}\$ and numerically, the speed of light is 299,792,458 m / s which approximates to \$2.998\times 10^8\$.
